# Ubuntu How to re-install bootloader

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partition

I accidently altered my partition table. Somehow I wiped it out completely and changed the disk label. The system has not been rebooted yet and I managed to rebuild it the way it originally was using the original structure and label however I need to re-install a new bootloader for the new MBR. I have Ubuntu 14.04TLS running inside VirtualBox on a Windows 7 machine. Is there a way to do this without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "grub-install" from a terminal? You will need to be root or use sudo.

```
grub-install
```

or

```
sudo grub-install
```

To see which version you have you can run:

```
grub-install --version
```

GRUB1 is versions <= 0.98. Also on the boot loader screen, it should say if it is "GRUB" or "GRUB2".

Comment: Thanks - I believe that did it although the big test wont come until I re-boot. I ran sudo grub-install /dev/sda and it reported back "Install finished. No errors reported".

Comment: I noticed however that I have Grub2 also installed. How can I tell whether the system is using Grub or Grub2?

Comment: If you want to find what version of grub you are running run "grub-install --version". Grub 1 is versions <=0.98. Also on the boot loader screen, it should say if it is "GRUB" or "GRUB2".